# Telegram cli bot with pyrogram limits

Tags: python-3.x, bots, client, pyrogram

I use the pyrogram library to develop the client robot, I set it up so that the robot connects to 15 phone numbers and sends messages in order with its proxies.
These 15 accounts are members in 300 joint groups! , every 15 accounts will be activated, respectively, and the text they have to send will be sent to these 300 groups.
In the form of the following process :

The first account is responsible for sending messages to the first 20 groups and the second account is responsible for sending messages to the second 20 groups, respectively ....

The question is, are pyrograms or telethons or these libraries restricted by the telegram? And the accounts get baned??

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get a flood wait if you try to send too many messages using a account.

Here is code to avoid flood wait https://docs.pyrogram.org/faq/how-to-avoid-flood-waits#how-to-avoid-flood-waits
to prevent flood wait you can add a delay for sending messages

```
await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Don't forget to import the asyncio library

Don't use `time.sleep()` because it is blocking, prefer to use `asyncio.sleep()` instead.